7 speed hub whistles
My 7 speed Nexus internal axle begins to whistle as speed increases, but noise stops when I slow down. Has nothing to do with the pedal crank.

Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Is there any way you could capture the sound for people to hear?  Does it only do it when the hub is loaded, or can you pick it up and spin it to make the noise?

Can you replicate the sound by hand-pedalling while the bike's back wheel is suspended off the ground?   A workstand or just some rope from a tree branch should be enough.
